# How to create my own table using EF in asp net core identity

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

Currently, I have EF working perfectly fine with asp net core identity. My web app allows users to login in 2 ways: using their local account and using their azure active directory account. However, only the allowed azure directory accounts are allowed to log in. Therefore, I need to create another table to hold those accounts to cross check when they log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new table for the Identity project, I suggest you could try to modify the identity EF's dbcontext with the new create model class.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
public class UserRelationship
{

    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Modify the ApplicationDbContext :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserRelationship> UserRelationships { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could enable the migration and update the database like this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) shows.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using exactly same approach that you proposed :)